# setVerboseLoggingEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type Cast.CastOptions.Builder

Tags: java, android, google-cast

I am using the CastCompanionLibrary-android  and it is throwing the following error all of a sudden. Any ideas ?

```
The method setVerboseLoggingEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type
Cast.CastOptions.Builder    VideoCastManager.java
/CastCompanionLibrary-android/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast
```

Its shows taht this method does infact exist in :
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastOptions.Builder.html

But when I drill into CastOptions it is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems I did an update with the Android SDK manager, but neglected to replace the old jar with the newly update jar.

Did this and it fixed the issue :)